# How to play video in node-webkit?

Tags: node-webkit

I am facing problem while playing video in Node-Webkit. Below is a small piece of code which is easily playable in Google Chrome, Firefox Browser but the not playable in node webkit. For this, I created an index.html file as:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop>
            <source src="https://doc-0o-1o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/jt8pk7gigobp59vrjgh53u3p8g7qenum/o37l8tolk3h4csn224kvl48gu9se31l1/1445882400000/11930958689028763066/11930958689028763066/0Bz1uVMPq87g1RXBiZGhGLUU2N00?e=download&nonce=8bb1u4fusajn4&user=11930958689028763066&hash=dtoaurvnsob2c2avkthk3ss1ierjm7iv" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

The index.html is easily runnable in any browser. The src video here I uploaded is an MP4 video which I have uploaded to my google drive. You can download one through the following link:-
[demo.mp4](https://doc-0o-1o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/jt8pk7gigobp59vrjgh53u3p8g7qenum/o37l8tolk3h4csn224kvl48gu9se31l1/1445882400000/11930958689028763066/11930958689028763066/0Bz1uVMPq87g1RXBiZGhGLUU2N00?e=download)

And to run this file in node-webkit, my package.json is as follows:-

```
{
    "name": "Demo Project",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Demo Project",
    "main": "index.html",
    "private": true,
    "keywords": [
        "node",
        "webkit",
        "win",
        "osx"
    ],
    "window": {
        "toolbar": true,
        "resizable": true,
        "width": 1400,
        "height": 750,
        "position": "center",
        "kiosk": false
    },
    "author": "Kamaldeep Singh",
    "license": "MIT"
}
```

Can anyone help me how to play a custom mp4 video in node-webkit HTML pages ?

**Note:** I am using angularjs in my project and have also tried [ngVideo](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngVideo) plugin.

Other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem ?